# Laravel 5.5 - migration not working

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration, database-migration

I am trying to run a migration that works perfectly fine on Laravel 5.2 version, but when I try to run it on the laravel 5.5 I get an error:

> In Connection.php line 664:
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid
>   default value for 'to_date' (SQL: create table `transactions` (`id`
>   int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `user_id` int
>   unsigned not null, `vehicle_id` int unsigned not null, `from_date` t
>   imestamp not null, `to_date` timestamp not null, `flight_number`
>   varchar(255) not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` ti
>   mestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate
>   utf8mb4_unicode_ci)
>
> In Connection.php line 458:
>                                                                                                     SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid
>   default value for 'to_date'

This it the migration for that table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTransactionsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->integer('vehicle_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('vehicle_id')->references('id')->on('vehicles');
            $table->timestamp('from_date');
            $table->timestamp('to_date');
            $table->string('flight_number');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('transactions');
    }
}
```

Why is it not working with the new version of laravel when it is working with the 5.2?

Comment: Table vehicles needs to be migrated before transactions table....do you have the vehicle table migration before this one?

Comment: yes, I have it before this one

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3602

Answer (score 2):

I found what was causing the problem, in **laravel 5.5** **MySQL** strict mode is enabled in **laravel config** `database.php` file by default, by setting the mode to `'strict' => false`, like in the version 5.3 I am able to run the migration.